# Is it possible to know when the user forget a BLE device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My app interacts with a BLE device that requires pairing. The question I have is the following.

Say that my phone is already paired with the device in which case is listed under Settings > Bluetooth > Devices. Is there a way for the app to know if the user went to Settings > Bluetooth and forget the device? When this occurs, connecting to my device from the app will require pairing again and I would like to know this before I make the connection so that I can properly show a message to the user saying i.e. "you are about to pairing with this device..."

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't believe that there is any visibility from CBCentralManager or from the CBPeripheral object as to whether it is currently paired.  All you can do is attempt to notify or indicate on the encrypted characteristic and iOS will display a dialog if necessary

Answer (score -1):

I thought BLE devices did not require pairing, like classic bluetooth.  In code you still have to search for devices with the service you want and connect to them, but this different than the pairing bluetooth list the user sees.  I am connected to several BLE devices, but do not see them in any iPhone settings screen.

Comment: If a BLE characteristic is flagged as requiring encryption then a pairing process will be initiated when the device attempts to read that characteristic.